# Question about the unconditional variance in the ARCH(1) model

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, garch

I am studying the ARCH model for the first time and have encountered a step in the derivation that I don't fully understand. The context is as follows:

ARCH(1) model is defined by the equations (as per Chapter 14 of "Introduction to Econometrics" by Carter Hill):

\begin{aligned}
y_t &= \beta_0 + e_t \\
e_t | I_{t-1} &\sim N(0, h_t) \\
h_t &= \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 e_{t-1}^2, \quad \alpha_0 > 0, \quad 0 \leq \alpha_1 < 1.
\end{aligned}

When conditional on $e_{t-1}^2$, the standardized errors are standard Normal:
$$
\left(\frac{e_t}{\sqrt{h_t}} \bigg| I_{t-1}\right) = z_t \sim N(0, 1).
$$
Because this distribution does not depend on $e_{t-1}^2$, it follows that the unconditional distribution of $z_t = \left(e_t/\sqrt{h_t}\right)$ is also $N(0, 1)$, and that $z_t$ and $e_{t-1}^2$ are independent. Thus, we can write:
$$
E\left(e_t\right) = E\left(z_t\right)E\left(\sqrt{\alpha_0 + \alpha_1 e_{t-1}^2}\right)
$$
and
$$
E\left(e_t^2\right) = E\left(z_t^2\right)E\left(\alpha_0 + \alpha_1 e_{t-1}^2\right) = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 E\left(e_{t-1}^2\right).
$$
From the first of these equations, we get $\ E(e_t) = 0$ because $\ E(z_t) = 0 $. From the second of the equations, we get $\ \text{var}(e_t^2) = E(e_t^2) = \frac{\alpha_0}{(1 - \alpha_1)}$ because $\ E(z_t^2) = 1$ and $\ E(e_t^2) = E(e_{t-1}^2)$.

However, in the second equation, it uses "the fact" that $E\left(e_t^2\right) = E\left(e_{t-1}^2\right)$. I don't understand how this equality is derived based on the assumptions provided in the ARCH(1) model.

Could someone please help me understand the reasoning behind this step? I would greatly appreciate any insights or explanations that could clarify this part of the derivation.

For those interested in the source, this content is extracted from Chapter 14 on the ARCH model in the book "Introduction to Econometrics" by Carter Hill.

Comment: Given a stationary stochastic process $\{X_t\}$, both $\mathbb{E}(X_t)$ and $\mathbb{E}(X_{t-1})$ refer to the same unconditional distribution $F_{X}$. Now insert $e^2$ in place of $X$.

Comment: @Richard Hardy 
Is this part combining with the fact the $\alpha_1$ has an absolute value smaller than 1 tells us that this 'stochastic process' is stationary?
$E\left(e_t^2\right) = E\left(z_t^2\right)E\left(\alpha_0 + \alpha_1 e_{t-1}^2\right) = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 E\left(e_{t-1}^2\right)$

Like, we can see $E\left(e_{t}^2\right)$ as the $X_t$ in $X_t = c + \phi X_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t$

Comment: @RichardHardy Isn't that circular?  The issue is that the ARCH equations do not assume stationarity: that needs to be demonstrated, which is what this question is asking.  After all, consider the case where $\alpha_1 \ge 1.$

Comment: I did not think the question was asking to prove stationarity, but I suppose you are right about circularity.

Comment: Is my previous comment invalid because it was based on the information you provided in your first response?